# VLC frame freezing on WPF user interface

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I have a WPF user interface which is contains 2 [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) element and some `Image` and `Datagrid`es that are updating frequently.
Each of These 2 VLC elements plays a stream from file or IP-Camera.
Other elements on the UI, update frequently during every minute and it's not a routine action. The instruction of these updates are coming from another `Thread` in the program and update UI with `Invoke`.

The problem is the VLC player element, freezes on a random frame.
Any idea about the possible causes?

Additional info: I'm using VLC 2.2.0 x86 and VS2013.

**Edit**: Adding some code:

WPF Code:

```
<Grid Name="_cameraBox" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Visibility="Collapsed" >
    <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="myVlcControl1" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="12" CornerRadius="10">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=myVlcControl1, Path=VideoSource}" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image Source="/Resources/Images/Logo.png" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
private void LoadTheStream(int streamNumber, string streamAddress)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {           
        if(InitialPrameters.UsingViedo)
        {
            streamAddress = "file:///" + streamAddress;
        }
        var vlc = (Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl) this.FindName("myVlcControl" + streamNumber.ToString());
        vlc.Stop();
        vlc.Media = new LocationMedia(streamAddress);
        vlc.Play();
    }));
}
```

and Events to Update UI code:

```
private void UpdateImageOnUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var args = e as UIUpdateEventArgs;
    ShowTheFrame(args.StreamNumber, args.SnapShot, args.FrameCrop);
}

private void ShowDetectedFrame(int streamNumber, Bitmap snapShot, Bitmap frameCrop)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var snapShotCtrl = (System.Windows.Controls.Image) FindName("_snapShot" + streamNumber.ToString());
        var frameCropCtrl = (System.Windows.Controls.Image) FindName("_frameCrop" + streamNumber.ToString());

        var snapShotImage = GeneralFunctions.ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(snapShot);
        var frameCropImage = GeneralFunctions.ConvertToBitmapImageFromBitmap(frameCrop);

        snapShotCtrl.Source = snapShotImage;
        frameCropCtrl.Source = frameCropImage;

        snapShotImage.Freeze();
        frameCropImage.Freeze();
    }));
}
```

Comment: There are half a dozen or so different ways to incorporate VLC into a WPF app - which one are you using? Can you post some code that shows how your player(s) are set up?

Comment: @goobering: Thanks. I added some code to my question. hope it helps.

Comment: That's useful, thanks - you might want to incorporate 'I'm using the Vlc.DotNet library to...' in the question somewhere. Unfortunately that library has a number of issues at the moment (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues). If you can't identify the problem there you may have to resort to adding the Vlc.DotNet source code to your project and stepping through it to track down the issue. It may also be worth commenting out your UI updating code and replacing it with something trivial to test whether it's interfering with the VLC control.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your link. I've upgraded all my codes to last version, but still have the problem.

Comment: This library has never ever worked correctly, we've been trying to use it for years now with no success.